# Laravel - Query for Aging Report using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have MySQL query that I want to convert to Laravel.

```
SELECT client_id,
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due_date) AS days_past_due,
SUM(IF(days_past_due = 0, amount_due, 0)),
SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 1 AND 30, amount_due, 0)),
SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 31 AND 60, amount_due, 0)),
SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 61 AND 90, amount_due, 0)),
SUM(IF(days_past_due > 90, amount_due, 0))
FROM invoices
GROUP BY client_id
```

I want to create a current,30, 60, 90, day aging reports in Matrix Format using Laravel query.

For example,

ClientName    Current    1-30    31-60    >90    Total

AAA                      3000    1500             4500

BBB                              2000       200   2200

TOTAL                        3000 3500      200   6700

I want to get the report like this. when user enters the date, it should check with duedate. when entered date is > due_date, get the aging days.

if aging agin days is today then get netAnmount and display in current column,

if difference is 1-30 days then next column...etc...

how to get query for this?

Comment: See: [Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries)

Answer (score 1):

I use subQuery in Laravel maybe can help you.

```
$invoice = Invoice::select(\DB::raw('ledgers.id,invoices.invoice_no,invoices.invoice_date,invoices.invoice_due,invoices.invoice_balance,DATEDIFF("'.$request->input('to_date').'", invoices.invoice_date) AS days_past_due'))
                       ->join('quotations','quotations.id','=','invoices.quotation_id')
                        ->join('ledgers','ledgers.id','=','quotations.ledger_id')
                        ->where('invoices.invoice_date','<=',$request->input('to_date'))
                        ->whereNotIn('invoices.status',[1,2]); 
$agingReport = Ledger::select(\DB::raw('a.id,ledgers.name,a.invoice_no,a.invoice_date,a.invoice_due,a.invoice_balance,a.days_past_due,CASE WHEN a.days_past_due =0 then a.invoice_balance else 0 end as month,
                            CASE WHEN a.days_past_due >0 and a.days_past_due <= 30 then a.invoice_balance else 0 end as aging30days,
                            CASE WHEN a.days_past_due >30 and a.days_past_due <= 60 then a.invoice_balance else 0 end as aging60days,
                            CASE WHEN a.days_past_due >60 and a.days_past_due <= 90 then a.invoice_balance else 0 end as aging90days,
                            CASE WHEN a.days_past_due >90 then a.invoice_balance else 0 end as more30days'))
                            ->from(\DB::raw('('.$invoice->toSql().') as a '))
                            ->mergeBindings($invoice->getQuery())
                            ->join('ledgers','ledgers.id','=','a.id')
                            ->get();
return response()->json($agingReport);
```